# Syntax error on line 17 regarind variable. I'm trying to make a program that takes in points of a triangle, and outputs the area via Heron's formula

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
import math

print ("First point")
print ("(A,B)")
A = input ("A")
B = input ("B")
print ("Second point")
print ("(C,D)")
C = input ("C")
D = input ("D")
print ("Second point")
print ("(C,D)")
E = input ("E")
F = input ("F"


side_A = sqrt( pow((A - C),2) + pow((B - D),2))
print(side_A)
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] and full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here:

- You don't import `sqrt` and `pow` from the math library, this needs to be imported with `from math import sqrt, pow`
- You don't convert the input to an `int` and the program can't perform operations with `str`'s

Fixed code:

```
from math import sqrt, pow

print("First point")
print("(A,B)")
A = input("A")
B = input("B")
print("Second point")
print("(C,D)")
C = input("C")
D = input("D")
print("Second point")
print("(C,D)")
E = input("E")
F = input("F")

side_A = sqrt( pow((int(A) - int(C)),2) + pow((int(B) - int(D)),2))
print(side_A)
```

Comment: you have to import `pow` also

Comment: @komatiraju032 Hmmm. it works without importing for me but I'll add it anyway. Thanks :)

Comment: Would int(side_a) convert it into an integer? I'm very new to Python.

Comment: You could do `side_a = int(side_a)` or `side_a = int(input("A"))`